# What to do when finding blood in eggs

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, disposal, eggs, blood

When cooking something with eggs, I always check the eggs for bloodspots. But I wonder, if I find a blood spot, do I need to throw the whole egg away or can I take the blood out with a spoon and use the non bloody part?

Answer (score 3):

[See this article from Rabbi Moshe Dovid Lebovits](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/eggs/). In short, technically you could just remove the blood spot itself.  However common practice today, barring extenuating circumstances, is to throw out the entire egg.

Comment: Are you OK with me updating your answer with some of my answer's info and deleting mine?

Comment: Is this true in all countries?

Comment: @DoubleAA: From the Teshuvos I would venture to say for sure Israel and the USA.

Answer (score 3):

> The following poskim say the metzius is that there are no roosters at
>   egg farms so chickens do not mate and produce eggs which are fertile.
>   Therefore, if one does find a blood spot in an egg, **all he has to do
>   is throw out the blood spot and he then may eat the rest of the egg**:
>   Yechaveh Da’as 3:57, Yabea Omer Y.D. 2:5, Minchas Yitzchok 4:56,
>   Opinion of Horav Sheinberg Shlita quoted in Divrei Chachumim page
>   185:20. See Be’er Moshe 5:129. Refer to Aruch Ha’shulchan 66:32.
>
> However, since eggs are inexpensive, rather than trying to remove a blood spot,
>   some people still throw out the whole egg.
>   (Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society ibid:footnote 21. Refer to OU document I-184 where the opinion of
>   Harav Hershel Schachter Shlita is quoted as saying that the women
>   throw away any egg with a blood spot.)

—from http://www.kashrut.com/articles/eggs/

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate (even with the same source) of the preexisting answer?

Comment: @msh210: I think it is. He posted it as I was. I have no problem deleting mine, however I think mine is clearer and includes the sources. Perhaps you can update Shalom's answer with mine and then delete mine.

Comment: +1 `where the opinion of Harav Hershel Schachter Shlita is quoted as saying that the women throw away any egg with a blood spot` So his opinion is that women throw 'em out. It sounds like a factual question like that shouldn't be dependent on opinion.